# Using BCP to import data to SQL Server while preserving accents, Asian characters, etc

Tags: sql-server, import, bcp

I'm trying to import a PostgreSQL dump of data into SQL Server using bcp. I've written a Python script to switches delimiters into '^' and eliminate other bad formatting, but I cannot find the correct switches to preserve unicode formatting for the strings when importing into SQL Server.

In Python, if I print out the lines that are causing me trouble, the row looks like this with the csv module:

```
['12', '\xe4\xb8\x89\xe5\x8e\x9f \xe3\x81\x95\xe3\x81\xa8\xe5\xbf\x97']
```

The database table only has 2 columns: one `integer`, one `varchar`.

My statement (simplified) for creating the table is only:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[example](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](max)
    )
```

And to run bcp, I'm using this line:

```
c:\>bcp dbo.example in fileinput -S servername -T -t^^ -c
```

It successfully imports about a million rows, but all of my accented characters are broken.

For example, "Böhm, Rüdiger" is turned into "B+¦hm, R++diger". Does anyone have experience with how to properly set switches or other hints with bcp?

**Edit**: `varchar` switched to `nvarchar`, but this does not fix the issue. This output in Python (reading with CSV module):

```
['62', 'B\xc3\xb6hm, R\xc3\xbcdiger']
```

is displayed as this in SSMS from the destination DB (delimiters matched for consistency):

```
select * from dbo.example where id = 62
62;"B├╢hm, R├╝diger"
```

where in pgAdmin, using the original DB, I have this:

```
62;"Böhm, Rüdiger"
```

Comment: What encoding does the text file have that contains your dump??

Comment: `$ file -bi <filename>` returns: `text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 3):

You may need to modify your BCP command to support wide character sets (note the use of -w instead of -c switch)

```
bcp dbo.example in fileinput -S servername -T -t^^ -w
```

[BCP documentation reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve unicode change varchar to nvarchar...

Comment: I modified the question and tried this.  I appended the results of the change in an edit.  Unfortunately, no dice -- didn't preserve accents.

Comment: Hmmmm. Try adding the -w switch in the bcp command. Something like the following should do the trick "c:\>bcp dbo.example in fileinput -S servername -w -T -t^^ -c"

Comment: Also if you've got control of your output try changing it to a txt file instead of csv, that's got around some issues for me in the past.

Comment: @CraigOttley-Thistlethwaite Actually `-c` and `-w` are incompatible... "-c is not compatible with -w.", taken from the description of the `-c` option in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15