# BCP -w copying 0 rows without error message

Tags: bcp

I am trying to ingest the following .txt file with content

```
2|Jürgen
3|Jürgen
4|Jürgen
```

delimited by `|`. The 2nd column is accented letters, as I want to test sql table preserving accented letters.

The sql table to be ingested are defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [stage].[bcp_test](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[TERM] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL)
```

If I do a simple insertion, `insert into stage.bcp_test values(1,'Jürgen')`
I can see the accent Jürgen preserved in the table.

But when I tried to insert the 3 rows in the sample file through bcp

```
bcp stage.bcp_test in "test.txt" -S dbservername -c -t "|" -T -F 1 -b 20000 -m 1 -e error.txt
```

Jürgen becomes J├╝rgen.

[image: db screenshot]

Based on some suggestions, I change -c to -t. So the new bcp command becomes

```
bcp stage.bcp_test in "test.txt" -S dbservername -w -t "|" -T -F 1 -b 20000 -m 1 -e error.txt
```

However, 0 rows are copied without any error message.
[image: error message]

Is there anything that I missed? I tried to search different places but cannot find a solution. Is it okay for me to bcp a .txt file using bcp -w?

===========================
Regarding Pa1's suggestion,what I got in my sql server is as follow:

[image: Pa1 answer]

Slightly different from his post, maybe because of sql version?

My Sql Server Version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (X64)

===========

Add on: Pa1's solution works. Depends on how the file is encoded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220450/using-bcp-to-import-data-to-sql-server-while-preserving-accents-asian-character
Here links to a very old post suggesting using bcp -w to fix the accented letters issue. But there is not much follow-up suggesting whether the issues are resolved.

Comment: Pa1's solution works, without use -w.
But I am still a little confused a bit this -c and -w thing. Welcome answers.

Answer (score 3):

This seems similar to [character encoding issue with the BCP and ó](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082845/character-encoding-issue-with-the-bcp-and-%C3%B3)

1. `-w` expects tab separated data based on bcp documentation. So replace pipes with tab and try?
2. To ensure that text is inserted properly, try specifying the [code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#C) in your bcp command

```
-C { ACP | OEM | RAW | code_page }
```

3. If you are using the `-C code_page` option then you need to match the code_page to the encoding of the file you are trying to ingest.
   The complete list is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/code-page-identifiers)

Here is the trial on my system:

- For ANSI Text

```
bcp stage.bcp_test in "test.txt" -S dbservername -c -C ACP -t "|" -T -F 1 -b 20000 -m 1 -e error.txt
```

[Results before and after using ACP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeXdf.png)

- For UTF-8 encoded text

```
bcp stage.bcp_test in "test.txt" -S dbservername -c -C 65001 -t "|" -T -F 1 -b 20000 -m 1 -e error.txt
```

- Using -w (change text to tab sperated)

```
bcp stage.bcp_test in "test.txt" -S dbservername -w -T -F 1 -b 20000 -m 1 -e error.txt
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggesting. using -c does work.
However, the premise is to preserve the accented letters, while using -c simply ignores that requirement. So the discussion is still to use -w, the unicode bulk insertion.
While keeping -w, adding a -C ACP did not solve my problems.

Comment: Following on, oh, I see your point of using -c -C ACP. The result is better, but still slightly off, i.e. not preserving the exact accents. I cannot attach picture here.Will pose in my main question body with the results.

Comment: Hi @YanTianqi. The sample file I used was using ANSI encoding. If the encoding is UTF-8 then you are right it won't work. For UTF-8 you need to specify `-C 65001`. Could this be the fix?

Comment: Hi Pa1, great, by using -c 65001, I manage to preserve the accented letters. Thanks.